# Windows 8 Tile Color

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, windows-8.1

With Windows 8.1, the start screen tiles for desktop apps seem to have all sorts of colors. It seems to be based on the color of the icon or something. Anyways, this makes the screen look messy.

With Windows 8.0 the start screen tile color was uniformly determined by the accent color you chose. Is there any way to return to this configuration?

Comment: Unless the configuration options allow you to choose the color scheme you want, the functionality you describe, was changed to response to feedback.  In other words nobody really liked it so it was changed.